# Making a Java Program Stereo-3D

Tags: java, stereo-3d, stereoscopy, anaglyph-3d

I was wondering if its possible to convert a java application (or any application) to stereo-3D *(like, with the red-and-blue glasses)*.

Is there any tool or framework that does this?

Comment: I'm not going to click 'close' -> 'not a real question' but I really should... please re-phrase this, it's very difficult to know exactly what you're saying.

Comment: This would ideally be done at the graphics card driver level (on a card that supports stereoscopic 3D), at which point you're not in Javaland anymore.

Comment: And what you want to see in 3D from a 2D Java (or any application)? You will just get the same 2D rectangles, in the best case.

Comment: I suppose what I am looking for is some way to programmaticly make a java swing application show depth that can be viewed using 3d glasses. But leave the rest of the screen normal. Only affect my application.

Comment: @Joe, I recommend going ahead and voting to close, and then voting to reopen if and when the post is improved.

Comment: Start writing a webcomic, grow a devoted, geeky fanbase for it, wait for April 1 and ask them to do this for you.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017067

Comment: What's with the "not a real question"? It seems perfectly clear to me. What are you not understanding about it, Joe?

Comment: @DJClayworth - please view the history of the question, I won't quote it here. Suffice it to say wanting something "3d" but not "3d graphics" is confusing.

Comment: My apologies, the original question was in fact extremely confusing. I wish there was a better way of dealing with this kind of thing.

Comment: I think SO probably has the best model available. Imagine the nightmare having multi-dimensional comment threads to go with versioned questions...

Answer (score 4):

The most common way to go about this is to work with JOGL, which is a thin Java layer over the OpenGL package. OpenGL supports stereoscopic 3D when paired with appropriate hardware. You will need to be using the right hardware, i.e. graphics card, as not all will support stereoscopy.

Here are some links that will get you started with JOGL and stereoscopy:

- [Fivedots](http://fivedots.coe.psu.ac.th/~ad/jg2/jogl4/index.html)
- [Stereo capabilities](http://phoenix.goucher.edu/~jillz/cs320/docs/javadoc_public/net/java/games/jogl/GLCapabilities.html)

Be aware that JOGL is a very low level package, and not easy to learn or work with. You certainly won't be able to 'convert' your Java app to 3D with it, unless it was written in JOGL to start with.

In the interests of comprehensive answers, it is also possible to do this in Java3D, which is a higher-level easier-to-use package than JOGL.

- [Sample program](http://www.interactivemesh.org/testspace/j3dmeetsswing.html)

Answer (score 3):

Have a look here: 
Java 3D meets Swing -> Stereoscopic 3D Rendering / JCanvas3DAnaglyph -> Sample Stereoscopic 3D
http://www.interactivemesh.org/testspace/j3dmeetsswing.html

August, InteractiveMesh

Answer (score 1):

The Canvas3D class in the [java 3d documentation](http://download.java.net/media/java3d/javadoc/1.5.2/index.html) gives a basic overview of it in mixed mode rendering. basically you would use two off screen Canvas3D's to render each eye and then combine  the images and display to user. see  [anaglyph demo](http://code.google.com/p/anaglyph-java3d-demo/)